# How do I filter out empty objects in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter

I hope you can help me.

I am creating a map using mapbox-gl and I am rendering some coordinates [lon, lat].

Some values are *null* though, so I am trying to filter them out using a reducer, but for those empty values I am only creating an empty object I can't delete and getting an error (filteredPositions.lon -> error: Property 'lon' does not exist on type '{}')

How can I only render those clusters with not null values? Here is my code:

```
    <Cluster ClusterMarkerFactory={clusterMarker} zoomOnClick>
    {systems.map(({ last_position, id }) => {

        const filteredPositions = Object.entries(last_position).reduce((a,[k,v]) => (v == null ? a : {...a, [k]:v}), {})

        return (
          <SystemMarker
            key={id}
            coordinates={[filteredPositions.lon, filteredPositions.lat]}
            heading={0}
            id={id}
            onClick={onSystemSelect}
          />
        )
    })}
    </Cluster>
```

Comment: is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAXDAhmAnjAvDA3gFAwkxhoC2ApqgOQCyAlgNZW0A0xpjAJqmAFcANkM6kY0NFBplhoriQAOAJxCLUARgBMAZgAshAL4BuQmYBmAsMCiNwMc4yHTlAUQqKomAGpohAqggACgQUdCwASlQMbCJxcxBlGCChKlgqMChlbEYwOCQIggVxGEZzZIBCUIBtDKzMAF1CuJLWnipU6XzEWszshtNWkkNikeLlNIFlPNDTMdBIEFSAOiEQAHMgx2cqNw8vX39AkIKI0yA) what you need?

Comment: Thank you, but it works like my reducer, without solving my issue, as the values in the object are either both of them null or not null. When they are null an empty object gets created, what I am trying to do is to delete the empty objects.

Comment: Oh, just check if `Object.entries` is empty and do `delete obj[prop]`. If you want to delete an object raw you'll have to do `obj = undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reducer is supposed to do some computations on the elements of a list and return only one element. The typical use case is to compute the sum of the elements of a list:

```js
let list = [1,2,3,4,5]
let sum = list.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0); // 15
```

If you want to filter the list. there is a [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). try to use that.

```js
const filteredPositions = Object.entries(last_position).filter(([k,v]) => v !== null)
```

Comment: The second argument to `reduce()` does not need to be the same as one of the array elements, so I don't know that I'd say it is "supposed" to return an element of the array.  That's a typical use case, certainly, but not the only one.  I strongly agree that since `filter()` exists, you shouldn't reimplement it with `reduce()`.  But it's interesting to note that `reduce()` is in some sense a "general-purpose" array manipulator, since you can [implement map/filter/find with it](https://maurobringolf.ch/2017/06/implementing-map-filter-and-find-with-reduce-in-javascript/) but not vice versa.

Comment: thank you, what I needed was to just add a filter before mapping, thanks!